# M7S Access: Eval a String Containing a Variable?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to modify the Labels on a datasheet header.  The following command produces the desired result:

```
Forms!mainform![mySubform].Form.Controls("Label47").Properties("Caption") = "Test47"
```

My ultimate goal is to modify a bunch of Label Captions in a loop using a variable.  No success with:

```
dim intLabel as integer
dim strLabel as string

intLabel = 47  'the first Label "Label47"

do while intLabel < 99
    strLabel = "Forms!mainform![mySubform].Form.Controls('Label" & intLabel & "').Properties('Caption') = 'Test" & intLabel & "'"
    Eval (strLabel)
    intLabel - intLabel + 1
Loop
```

Any suggestions to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why the change to single-quotes (`'`) instead of double-quotes (`"`)?  To match your original line, you want to use `strLabel = "Forms!mainform![mySubform].Form.Controls("Label" & intLabel).Properties("Caption") = "Test" & intLabel`

Comment: Umm, I cannot construct a valid string value without replacing the (") with (').  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry - let me rewrite that - I forgot you were creating a string within a string `strLabel = "Forms!mainform![mySubform].Form.Controls(""Label" & intLabel & """).Properties(""Caption"") = ""Test" & intLabel & """"`

Comment: OK, I got that! :)   The Eval (strLabel) line craps out:  2770 "Object referenced as an OLE object isn't an OLE object".  The resulting string is nicely formed as expected - matching the test string above.

Comment: I'm not used to Access's `Eval` command so I can't really comment on its limitations.  (Excel's version would only allow you to evaluate things that are accessible to Excel itself, i.e. you can't refer to objects that are part of user forms or code modules, etc.  And Excel's version won't allow you to perform assignments, just evaluate things.  So maybe Access's version is similarly constrained.)

Comment: Why do you want to use `Eval`?

Comment: I did no think I could execute a command containing a variable without first computing (Eval) its value>

Comment: Why don't you just do `Forms!mainform![mySubform].Form.Controls("Label" & intLabel).Properties("Caption") = "Test" & intLabel` and forget about `Eval` completely

Comment: There's no real difference between using a string literal such as `"Label47"` and a string variable containing that same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would forget the attempt to use `Eval` and just assign the values directly:

```
dim intLabel as Long
dim strLabel as String

intLabel = 47  'the first Label "Label47"

Do While intLabel < 99
    Forms!mainform![mySubform].Form.Controls("Label" & intLabel).Properties("Caption") = "Test" & intLabel
    intLabel - intLabel + 1
Loop
```

Comment: YowE3K, That produces the desired result.  Interesting.  Thanks!